# Conditional validation of the input field vue3 vuelidate

Tags: validation, vuejs3, vuelidate

I'm building conditional form with vue and stuck on how conditionally validate input field based on the previous users choice. I'll appreciate any help.

in the form I have dropdown menu with payment choices (terminal, payconiq, cash etc).
Second input field is the link user need to add. If user choose terminal, he should add to `link` input an IP Address. If not - url address.

I receive a paymentId from options with `@click`, send it to the store and get it from the store with computed property.

The problem is that my [vuelidate](https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate) does not read the condition

```js
const typefromStore = computed(() => paymentStore.paymentType) // here I get typeId from store

const validations = {
  description: { required },
  type: { required },
  link: {
    required,
    type: typefromStore.value === 1? ipAddress : url // always checks for url and give an error if I need to input IP address  
  },
}
```

I read documentation, but I didn't find how to check second input field based on the value of the previous. Only cases when previous field is invalid. But data from dropdown list is always valid.
I need to use the value of 'type' somehow to check conditionally value of link.

Answer (score 0):

```
Found the solution. May be will help someone. Needed to put validation in computed. No store needed

    let newMethod = reactive({
     instanceId: 1,
     description: '',
     type: -1,
     link: '',
     active: true,
    })

     const rules = computed(() => {
 
         const localRules = {
           description: { required },
           type: { required },
           link: {},
         }

         if (newMethod.type === 1) {
             localRules.link = {
             ipAddress,
             }
         } 
         else {
          localRules.link = {
             url,
         }
    }
      return localRules
    })

    const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, newMethod, { $autoDirty: true })
```